# How to handle background click event in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I develop a dialog can app setting extends `DialogFragment` in Android. I override `onDissmiss` method, but it can handle after close dialog.

I want to close dialog when only save successfully, like this:

> 1. Click background or click hardware's back button
> 2. Save to preference (Show progress icon)
> 3. Save successfully (Hide progress icon)
> 4. Close dialog

How to handle before close dialog? Or how to handle background click event?

Comment: What do you mean by `background click event`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 mDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mCallBackHandler.sendEmptyMessage(ACTION_DISMISS);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `onDismiss` was called after close dialog. :o

Answer (score 0):

You should call OnKeyListner on dialog, Try this:

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnDialogBackKeyPressed() :: onKey() : ");
                switch (event.getAction()) 
                {
                case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    return true;
                }

                switch (keyCode) 
                {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I want to dismiss when only save preference successfully

Comment: Do you @override onCreateDialog() method in your dialogFragmentClass ?

Comment: did you get answer ? last night I read documentation of [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). DialogFragment extends Fragment, so you can [tag:@override] [tag:onDestroyView()] and [tag:onDestroy()] methods in it. You can dismiss dialog with save preferences(opening [tag:ProgressDialog] in it)